# C segmentation fault in specific lines

Tags: segmentation-fault

Hello im new at C as you can understand. I get an segmentation fault with lines 26 - 31.
I mentioned where the falut begins below into code.
Im getting error message in [this online c compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler) and also code blocks says nothing just .exe file is stopping. But this code working perfectly in DevC++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int terim,s,z;
    int deger[terim][2];
    float alt_limit;
    float ust_limit;
    float toplam;
    float cikarma;

    printf("Denkleminizde kac adet terim var?\n");
    scanf("%d",&terim);

//#################
    for(s=0; s<terim; s++){  //----- segmentation fault begins
        printf("Lutfen %d. terimin katsayisini giriniz : ",s+1);
        scanf("%d",&deger[s][0]);
        printf("Lutfen %d. terimin us degerini giriniz:",s+1);
        scanf("%d",&deger[s][1]);
    }                          //----- segmentation fault ends



    printf("\nLutfen alt limit degerini giriniz\n>>:  ");
    scanf("%f",&alt_limit);
    printf("\nLutfen ust limit degerini giriniz\n>>:  ");
    scanf("%f",&ust_limit);


        cikarma = ust_limit - alt_limit;
        toplam = ust_limit + alt_limit;

    int tercih;

    printf("\n [ 1 ]  Rectangle Yontemi \n");
    printf("\n [ 2 ]  Midpoint Yontemi \n");
    printf("\n [ 3 ]  Trapezoid Yontemi \n");
    printf("\n [ 4 ]  Simpsons Yontemi \n");

    printf("Lutfen tercih ettiginiz yontemin numarasini tuslayiniz\n");
    scanf("%d",&tercih);

    float a_tabaninda , b_tabaninda , tplm_yarisi;
    float rec_sonuc,mid_sonuc;
    float trap_sonuc,simp_sonuc;

    a_tabaninda = pow(alt_limit,deger[z][1]);
    b_tabaninda = pow(ust_limit,deger[z][1]);
    tplm_yarisi = pow((alt_limit + ust_limit)/2,deger[z][1]);
    float zrec,zmid,ztrap,zsimp;
    switch(tercih){
        case 1:

            for(z=0; z<terim ;z++){


                rec_sonuc += ((deger[z][0])*pow(alt_limit,deger[z][1]));

            }

            zrec = (cikarma * rec_sonuc);
            printf("%.4f",fabs(zrec));

            break;

        case 2:

            for(z=0;z<terim;z++){

             mid_sonuc += ((deger[z][0]*pow((alt_limit + ust_limit)/2,deger[z][1])));

            }

            zmid = (cikarma * mid_sonuc);
            printf("%.4f",fabs(zmid));

            break;

        case 3:
            for(z=0;z<terim;z++){

             trap_sonuc += (((deger[z][0]*pow(alt_limit,deger[z][1]))+(deger[z][0]*pow(ust_limit,deger[z][1])))/2);

    }
            ztrap = (cikarma * trap_sonuc);
            printf("%.4f",fabs(ztrap));

            break;

        case 4:
                for(z=0;z<terim;z++){

             simp_sonuc += (deger[z][0]*pow(alt_limit,deger[z][1])) + 4*(deger[z][0]*pow((alt_limit + ust_limit)/2,deger[z][1])) + (deger[z][0]*pow(ust_limit,deger[z][1])) ;

    }
            printf("%.4f",fabs(cikarma/6*simp_sonuc));

            break;

        default:
            printf("Lutfen gecerli bir numara giriniz!\n");

    }


    return 0;
}
```

thanks for your help...

Comment: For a start, look at int deger[terim][2];.  terim is not initialized.  I've not looked beyond that, so there may be other issues too.

Comment: It is initialized. Problem isn't solved yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved. I'm defining

int deger[terim][2];

AFTER this line:

scanf("%d",&terim);

Don't know why but this code act differently in different operating systems and different type of compilers. But with this solution, it's works perfectly.

Thank all of you :)

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your code and compiled it and get a segmentation fault as you describe.

I then initialised **terim** to have an initial value of 100 and compiled again. Your program then runs without a segmentation fault provided I don't enter a value of 100 or more when you scanf into **terim**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int terim = 100,s,z; /* Initialise here */
    int deger[terim][2];
```

Here's the output I get from your program when I run it ...

```
Denkleminizde kac adet terim var?
2 
Lutfen 1. terimin katsayisini giriniz : 1
Lutfen 1. terimin us degerini giriniz:2
Lutfen 2. terimin katsayisini giriniz : 3
Lutfen 2. terimin us degerini giriniz:4

Lutfen alt limit degerini giriniz
>>:  5

Lutfen ust limit degerini giriniz
>>:  6

 [ 1 ]  Rectangle Yontemi 

 [ 2 ]  Midpoint Yontemi 

 [ 3 ]  Trapezoid Yontemi 

 [ 4 ]  Simpsons Yontemi 
Lutfen tercih ettiginiz yontemin numarasini tuslayiniz
1
1900.0000
```

I'm not commenting on whether your code is structured well, or otherwise.  I'm exclusively focusing on why you are getting the segmentation fault.

Hope this helps.